# What are the most needed things to build a Maven Project with restservice with JPA, spring and unit testing with pom.xml dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jpa, testing

It would be good if someone can post sample codes too! Thanks in advance!

i have tried this code for a bean class,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "language")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class Language {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "la_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "la_name")
    private String name;



    public Language() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Language(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Language [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }



}
```

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Use this spring configurator: [Start Spring](https://start.spring.io/)